# How to execute a command on a single file in a directory whilst looping though the directories recursively

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, wget

I have the following structure

```
/ Cardio
/../ High
/../ High / download.txt
/../ Low
/../ Low / download.txt
/../ Medium
/../ Medium / download.txt
/ Warm
/ Warm / download.txt
/ Cool
/ Cool / download.txt
```

So basically "Cardio" has folders, no files. High, Low, Medium, Warm and Cool have a file called download.txt

I would like to iterate through each folder recursively and if there's a download.txt file to run `wget` against it but I can't get it to work :-(

I have the following but it downloads the files into the folder I run the script from rather than saving it to the folder where the download.txt sits

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | while read fname; do wget -i ${fname}; done
```

Any suggestions?

**Update**

This seems to do it - any comments?

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -execdir wget -i download.txt \;
```

Comment: Using `execdir` is the solution here. You may want to split that out to an answer and accept it - it is perfectly fine here to answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: in case there are other "txt" files: `find . -type f -name "download.txt" -execdir wget -i {} \;`